# Cannot lowercase backreferenced string in Postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, string-function

I am trying to lowercase a backreferenced string but it wont work. :( I just want to lower the first character after root.

```
my_string = "<root>Here is July's best food</root>"
```

Correct one should be:

```
my_string = "<root>here is July's best food</root>"
```

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_string = regexp_replace(my_string, '<root>(.)', lower(E'<root>\\1'))
WHERE my_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `split_part()` and `lower()`

```
 select '<root>'||lower(split_part(split_part('<root>Here is July''s best food</root>',' ',1),'>',2)) || split_part('<root>Here is July''s best food</root>',split_part(split_part('<root>Here is July''s best food</root>',' ',1),'>',2),2)
```

Result:

```
 "<root>here is July's best food</root>"
```

---

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_string =  '<root>'||lower(split_part(split_part(my_string,' ',1),'>',2)) || split_part(my_string,split_part(split_part(my_string,' ',1),'>',2),2) 
WHERE my_id = 1;
```

*following function is optional*

You can make function like below

```
 create or replace function lower_first_word(txt text,del text) returns text as
$$
 select del||lower(split_part(split_part(txt ,' ',1),'>',2)) || split_part(txt ,split_part(split_part(txt ,' ',1),'>',2),2)
$$
language sql
```

and update

```
UPDATE my_table
    SET my_string = lower_first_word('<root>Here is July''s best food</root>','<root>')
    WHERE my_id = 1;
```

---

***OR***

Using `regex` and `substring()`

```
select lower(substring('<root>Here is July''s best food</root>',E'[A-Za-z<>]+'))||substring('<root>Here is July''s best food</root>',E'[^ ]* (.*)')
```

and the update statement is

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_string = lower(substring('<root>Here is July''s best food</root>', E '[A-Za-z<>]+')) || substring('<root>Here is July''s best food</root>', E '[^ ]* (.*)')
WHERE my_id = 1;
```